# Welches Verb gehört zum Nomen "Forensische Untersuchung"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verb-choice

> Der Gerichtsmediziner führt `eine forensische Untersuchung` auf das
>   Blut des Verbrechers durch um zu sehen, ob er am Mord teilgenommen hat oder
>   nicht.

Kann das Tätigkeitswort `durchführen` in diesem Kontext verwendet werden? Und ich bin mir sogar unsicher, ob der Substantiv `forensische Untersuchung` hier passt.

Comment: Side note: *Teilnehmen* und *Mord* passen nicht zusammen. Man *begeht* den Mord, man *leistet Beihilfe zum Mord* oder man *mordet durch Unterlassen von Hilfeleistung*.

Comment: @Em1 depends I'd say. If you want to express that someone was one, among a group of persons conducting the crime I'd go with "beteiligt sein". Of course when it comes to legal-talk, Juristendeutsch, then there are only those few distinct options you named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this. Both "forensische Untersuchung" and "durchführen" are correct here.
However:
It would be "**mit dem Blut**" or "**am Blut**".

Comment: Der Gerichtsmediziner führt eine forensische Untersuchung `am Blut` des Verbrechers durch um zu sehen, ob er den Mord `begangen hat` od. '......, er am Mord `beteiligt war`? Danke!

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Yea, both are correct.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Um sich nicht der Vorverurteilung schuldig zu machen, sollte man statt "Verbrecher" eher "Verdächtiger" sagen.

Comment: Again, this also depends: Does he examine the corpse to find traces of the suspect's blood? Then *auf das Blut* is correct. Does he examine the suspect's blood itself? Then he *führt eine ... am Blut ... durch*.